# Dynamic Combobox Form keeps on setting all comboboxes when trying to set a single one

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I've got a WinForm-Application that enables the user to dynamically add as many combobox lines as he requires. The issue is the fact, that when selecting a value in a single combobox the form keeps on setting all **cbs** to that value.

The code that dynamically adds a new row of comboboxes to the form is the following:

```
private void addRowSettingsTable(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Adds a new row to the table 
            Label attrLabel = new Label();
            attrLabel.Text = "Attribute:";
            tblFormSettings.Controls.Add(attrLabel);
            ComboBox cbAttributes = new ComboBox();
            cbAttributes.Name = ""+counter++;
            cbAttributes.DataSource = confFileSettings;
            tblFormSettings.Controls.Add(cbAttributes);
            listCBAttributes.Add(cbAttributes);
            Label valLabel = new Label();
            valLabel.Text = "Value:";
            tblFormSettings.Controls.Add(valLabel);
            TextBox tbValue = new TextBox();
            tblFormSettings.Controls.Add(tbValue);
            Button addButton = new Button();
            addButton.Text = "+";
            addButton.Click += addRowSettingsTable;
            tblFormSettings.Controls.Add(addButton);
            listTBValues.Add(tbValue);
        }
```

As one can see from the following picture, assigning one cb to a value changes all added cbs to that value.

Does anyone have an idea why this happens? I was pretty sure that creating a new ComboBox-Object for every one would not let me run into that issue.

[image]

Comment: Why is this tagged WPF?

Comment: Sry, my mistake. Will be removed shortly...

Comment: So they all share one DataSource?

Comment: Yes exactly, the datasource is a global list of strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give each ComboBox its own List DataSource based on the original:

```
cbAttributes.DataSource = new List<string>(confFileSettings);
```

Comment: Seemed like such an easy thing to do! Thanks